# Local webpage overrides with google-chrome in android

Tags: android, google-chrome

Recently found out about google-chrome [local overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-65/#overrides) when browsing on my computer and would like to be able to do the same when browsing with google-chrome on my android phone with the "desktop site" option activated. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Developper options are disabled on android. I tried on all available browser, but nothing worked. However, if you really need to debug on chromium based browser, use this: [Chromium browser](https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/chromium/android/download)
Here is the doc: [Chromium debugging on android](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/android_debugging_instructions.md)